# Hide an iframe from the opened page

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to hide an iframe but every time I close it, it just closes the page I've loaded inside it. So, when I click on the button that opens the iframe, it wont open again. Here is my code:

```
<a href="#" id="vcasa1">click</a>

<div id="casa001">
<iframe frameborder="5px" width="800px" height="630px" src="http://bienesraices.wall-  fine.mx/casa001.html" name="CV-001" allowtransparency="true" style="background-color:   transparent;" scrolling="no" noresize></iframe>
</div>
```

i use this function to open the iframe

```
$( "#vcasa1").click(function(){
      $("#casa001").slideDown(1200);
});
```

and this to close it

```
$( "#cerrar001").click(function(){

      $("#CV-001").fadeOut(600);

});
```

and this is the code of the "http://bienesraices.wall-fine.mx/casa001.html" page

```
<body style="background-color: transparent;">
<div id="CV-001" class="clearfix">
<div style="width:700px; height:400px;">
<div class="black2-35">

    <div style="margin-left:635px; position:absolute;">
    <a href="#" id="cerrar001">Cerrar</a>
    </div>
    <div id="title">
    <h1><strong>asdasdasasdasd</strong><h1 />
    </div>

  <h5><strong>asdasdasdasdasdsad</strong>
casaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasdaasdadsdasdasdasasdasda
sdasdasdasdasdasdasdaasdasdasdasdasasdadsdasdasdasasdasdas
dasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasda</ h5>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload the iFrame content. For different domain:

```
var iframe = $(FrameId);
iframe.attr('src', iframe.attr('src'));
```

If iFrame page is on same domain:

```
document.getElementById(FrameID).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

Complete code (actually there isn't any problem with reloading so you do not need any reload):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hide/show iframe</title>
        <script language="JavaScript" 
                type="text/javascript" 
                src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#toggleIframe').click(function(){
                    $('#myFrame').toggle('slow');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="toggleIframe">Toggle iFrame</button>
        <iframe style="border:0px;" width="200px" height="200px" 
                    src="test1.html" id="myFrame"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

You iFrame html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hide/show iframe</title>
        <script language="JavaScript" 
                    type="text/javascript" 
                    src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#toggleIframe').click(function(){
                    $('.content_wrapper').toggle('slow');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="toggleIframe">Toggle iFrame Content</button>
        <div class="content_wrapper" style="background:green;">
            <h2>All content goes here</h2>
        <div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This way you toggle the iFrame contents, but you need to show the toggle button always, else you cannot show the iFrame content again.

Comment: Hi could u please show me an example on how to use it?? im still really new with jquery thanks :)

Comment: Hi thanks again could this be done from the page opened on the iframe?? cause thats what i need the button im using to close the iframe its on the casa001.html content as u can see on the code ive posted thanks again for ur help

Comment: You can close it this way, but there is no way to open it again cause the content is gone. However you can use a trick, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show').click(function(){
        $('#frame').slideDown();
        });
    $('#show').hide();
    $('#mybtn').click(function(){
    $('#show').show();
    $('#frame').slideUp();
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#aaaaaa" style="text-align:center">
    <br>
   <a id="mybtn" href="#">click me</a>
    <br>
    <div id="frame">
    <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp" frameborder="0" name="test"    id="test"></iframe>
    </div>
    <a href='#' id='show'>Show</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Js Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/YVHAF/

Comment: would this work if i have the close button on the "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp" as i said i have it on my casa001.html cause thats what i need thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to `slideDown` an iframe that already Opened

Check out [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYQLx/3/)  here.

First close `iframe` using `slideUp` then Open it using `slideDown`

Comment: Hi thanks ive tried this but isnt working im callind the function from two separated files one im using to call the $("#vcasa1").live('click',function(){
            $("#casa001").slideDown(600);
           $("#CV-001").fadeIn(1200);
            });     and the other to call the     $("#cerrar001").live('click',function(){
          $("#casa001").slideUp(1200);
      $("#CV-001").fadeOut(600);

});          also as i said im loading it from different pages the iframe opens in the main indez page but opens the /casa001.html page